# Magento: don't send tax to paypal/don't show tax in paypal emails

Tags: magento, paypal, checkout

I'm using magento 1.7, and one of the payment options is Paypal (UK) express checkout.

The problem is that I don't want paypal to send out emails with any tax breakdown on, is there a more straightforward way of solving this (at the Magento or Paypal end) rather than hacking the core module to pass sub+tax as sub and 0 as tax?

I can see that a lot of the fields are mapped in Model/Api/Nvp.php, but can't immediately see where I'd modify these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I investigated, there is no easy configurable way to prevent taxes to be submitted to Paypal.

But indeed there is a core hack if you don't mind that only the total amount is submitted (no line items, no taxes).

Go to `System/Config/Paypal` and set `Transfer Cart Line Items` to `No`.
In your code go to function `_validate()` in class `Mage_Paypal_Model_Cart`.
At the end of this function add the following lines:

```
$this->_areItemsValid = false;
$this->_areTotalsValid = false;
```

Of course it is nicer to to rewrite this class in your `app/code/local` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Jaymz. I've tried this, and I now get no price information at all in Paypal, is that the expected behaviour? As in there is not even a total on the first Paypal page one gets to.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are right. I only tried this for Paypal Standard.
But this looks like a bug in the Paypal extension to me. Even without the code changes it won't show any amount if 'Transfer Cart Line Items' is disabled. On Paypal Standard this works like a charm.

Comment: Since you tested this on Paypal Standard and said it works there I'm going to mark correct as it might solve it for others! Thanks for the answer.